# positional argument OSX

Tags: python, arguments

mac terminal says im passing two positional arguments into the take_damage method...

```
from enemy import Enemy

random_monster = Enemy("Basic enemy", 12, 1)
print(random_monster)

random_monster.take_damage(4)
print(random_monster)
```

and the other file is here ______________________

```
class Enemy:

def __init__(self, name="Enemy", hit_points = 0, lives = 1):
    self.name = name
    self.hit_points = hit_points
    self.lives = lives

def take_damage(damage):
    remaining_points = self.hit_points - take_damage
    if remaining_points >= 0:
        self.hit_points = remaining_points
        print("i took {} damage and have {} left".format(damage, self.hit_points))
    else:
        self.lives -= 1

def __str__(self):
    return "Name: {0.name}, Lives: {0.lives}, Hitpoints: {0.hit_points}".format(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

All methods need to take `self` as well as any other arguments.

```
def take_damage(self, damage):
```

Comment: ahh figured it out thanks to you! i also tried to subtract take_damage instead of damage. silly learning mistakes lol